# Printing certain elements of a character vector based on condition and deleting the others

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, while-loop

I have a vector called fruits which contains names of 7 fruits. I want to print those fruit names which has more than or equal to 5 characters in the name.

```
fruits <- c("apple", "orange","pear","figs","avocado","plum", "kiwi")
j <- 1
while(j<=length(fruits)){

  if(nchar(fruits[j]>=5)){
    print(fruits[j])}
  else{
    remove(fruit[j])}
  j=j+1
}
```

Expected result is

```
[1] "apple"
[1] "orange"
[1] "avocado"
```

But what I get is

```
[1] "apple"
[1] "orange"
[1] "pear"
[1] "figs"
[1] "avocado"
[1] "plum"
[1] "kiwi"
```

It must also remove the fruit name with less than 5 character from the vector.

Comment: Check this line `remove(fruit[j])}` you use `fruit` instead of `fruits`

Comment: `fruits[nchar(fruits)>=5]`

Comment: `remove` can remove an object (like the `fruits` vector entirely), but not a specific element from a vector. You also may have intended `nchar(fruits[j]) >= 5` ... note ending parenthesis placement after [j]...

Comment: If you want to remove an element from a vector by numerical index, you could do something like `fruits <- fruits[-j]`...but @jogo's comment would be best for subsetting...